# How can I send auto email reminder everyday to the shared users using excel online

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks, office365

I have shared an Excel sheet to few people. I want to remind them to update it at a scheduled time through email automatically.

Is it possible with web based excel sheet? It is a OneDrive document.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, OneDrive does not support any VBA action. You would have to run an external process. See [Internal Server Error to send Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192957/internal-server-error-to-send-form/32194084#32194084).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to notify the users from inside the Excel sheet, or is a 3rd party solution acceptable?

One way of doing it, would be using a Azure WebJob, and just run a mail script once every day.

Another solution might be an [Azure Logic](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/logic/) app, to send out the mails every day.